# use of cron - magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, magento-2.0, crontab

I have configured the cron by refering this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html), yes I have successfully configured. now I can able to see newly created three cron logs file they are

**magento.cron.log**, it is logging like

```
Ran jobs by schedule.
```

**setup.cron.log** still now it is empty

**update.cron.log**, it is logging like

```
readiness check failed
```

in log file they just print message every minutes, I felt not much details present in the log.

my question is what is the use of cron and cron logs, is it helpful to debug?

please suggest neat and simple way to understand cron and cron logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware that cron logging is not helpful and we're working on a solution. It's concerning that you have `Readiness check failed` in your log.

Try to run the update cron job from the command line:

`<your Magento install dir>/update/cron.php`

See if you get other errors that might help to isolate the issue. Also, [on this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/cron.html), try **Solution: cron running from incorrect PHP binary** to make sure your cron is set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

Cron is a scheduled job that sends mails and other stuff. As long as you get the 'ran jobs by schedule' in your log it works. u can check if it works by just creating an account and seeing if the mail arrives. That mail is triggered by a cron job.